# NETCFv35.Messages.EN.cab installation

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

So I get those typical message below on my Window CE 6.0 , upon reading more about it I found the file NETCFv35.Messages.EN.cab under C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\Diagnostic

*“An error message is available for this exception but cannot be displayed because these messages are optional and are not currently installed on this device. Please install ‘NETCFv35.Messages.EN.wm.cab’ for Windows Mobile 6.0 and above or  ‘NETCFv35.Messages.EN.cab’ for other platforms. Restart the application to see the message.“*

I copy that cab file and run it on my Window CE 6.0 device, everything went smooth, it asks me for the installation ect... but how do I know that's all there is? does it work with just the above steps? I look over the internet, except there are some posts about doing something with the mobile device version of the cab file there are not much.

Do I need to include its dll as a reference in my c# application or does this installation just works directly with the .NET 3.5 CF that is already on my device and produce more detail error messages?

Any helps are appreciated...

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to include "it's dll as a reference to your application" or anything like that. If you need to distribute it, ensure it's shipped with your application along with the relevant .NETCFv3.5 cab file and any other staging dependencies.

This file contains the actual messages corresponding to exceptions raised by the .NET CF. The reason it isn't packaged into the standard .NET CF3.5 cab is twofold:

1. to keep the size of the deployment as small (compact) as possible for mobile devices
2. a "well designed" application shouldn't require these messages in production code because any and all exceptions raised by the CF ought to be handled in your application and replaced with user-friendly messages if necessary to display to the user.

the 2nd is of course sometimes difficult to achieve, but the idea is that this .CAB might not have to be deployed with production applications.

Comment: I only use this in my debug environment right now because I'm troubleshooting some IOException issue.  So base on what you say, what I do is enough correct? if I get any exception running my application I should now able to see a more detail version of that exception...

Comment: It's kind of like editing your web.config file to show yourself the YSODs, but not to the customers.

Answer (score 3):

- Extract SYCCFA~1.001 from NETCFv35.Messages.XX.wm.cab
- Rename it System.SR.dll
- Add it as reference to your application

From: http://tech.cybernet.lu/?p=522#comment-199